# Histogram styling and layout

Tags: plotting, histograms

1. Using `ChartLayout`, the histograms are tiled as expected as below, however the `ChartStyle` is not reflected (histograms with different colors was expected). What should I fix?

```
a = {1, 2, 2, 2, 1}; b = {1, 1, 1, 2};

Histogram[
  {a, b}, ChartLayout -> "Column", 
  ChartStyle -> {Opacity[.25, Red], Opacity[.25, Blue]}
]
```

[image]

2. Could rectangles in the two histograms be located side by side as shown in the example below? (I've searched docs but I couldn't find.)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bins = HistogramList[Join[a, b]][[1]];

heights = HistogramList[#, {bins}][[2]] & /@ {a, b};

BarChart[heights, 
 ChartLabels -> MovingAverage[bins, 2], 
 ChartStyle -> {Opacity[.25, Red], Opacity[.25, Blue]}, 
 BarSpacing -> {0, .5}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
styles = {Opacity[.25, Red], Opacity[.25, Blue]};

postProcess := ReplaceAll[r_Rectangle :> {Last[styles = RotateLeft[styles]], r}];


postProcess @ Histogram[{a, b}, ChartLayout -> "Column"]
```

[image]

```
postProcess @ Histogram[{a, b}, ChartLayout -> "Row"]
```

[image]